# Difference between calling command line directly or from makefile

Tags: command-line, makefile, mingw

I have a confusing problem concerning mingw make and windows command line (Win7):

I have a makefile which shall call a vbs file to convert .vds files to .png files. here is the code of the makefile (without the defined variables, you can see the result in the picture below).

```
VSD2PNG: $(VISIO_OUTPUT)
    @echo *** converting visio files to png files finished


define vsd_rule
$(1): $(call FILTER_FUNCTION,$(basename $(notdir $(1))),$(VISIO_FILES))
    $(VSD_SCRIPT) $$< $(VISIO_OUTPUT_DIR)
endef
$(foreach file,$(VISIO_OUTPUT),$(eval $(call vsd_rule,$(file))))
```

leads to

[image]

As you can see, the command should call .\tools\visio\convert(.vbs) with two arguments (input file & output directory). Surprising is that the same command executed in windows command line works fine. I tried some modifications to solve the problem (unsuccessfully):

- adding file extension to vbs-script leads to error 193, but I cannot find out, what that means.
- calling the script without any arguments should lead to a runtime-error in the script, but that leads to make error -1 again (or with file extension 193).
- using absolute path for script

Does anybody know more about the differences between calling a script directly from command line or from makefile, which should usually lead to the command line?

Comment: What happens when you try something simpler?

Comment: See second point of the listing: I tried to call only the vbs script without any arguments. That should lead to a runtime error of the vbs script, but it doesn't. So I think that it cannot find the script.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MinGW, so I can't diagnose the problem at a glance, but I can suggest some experiments. Post the simplest makefile that produces the error. Try having the rule call a script that really doesn't exist, and see if it gives the same error. Try having it call a `HelloWorld` with the same path, or the real script in the working directory.

Comment: using a target containing only the function call leads to the same problems. Calling another program (.exe) results in normal behaviour. Is it possible that you cannot run a .vbs script from make?

Comment: Can you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: Yep, but I am not allowed to upload it... :( So here are some instructions for a two-minute example:

1) Create a folder containing a vbs script called hello_world.vbs.
2) Write 'msgbox("hello world")' into that script file.
3) Create a makefile test_mk.mk containing one target:
test:
  .\hello_world.vbs
4) Use mingw-make with that makefile and compare the result to the result of the command line. Mingw-make will throw error 193 (I don't know, what that means) and the command line will popup the messagebox containing hello world. 

So I think that make cannot run vbs, but can't ensure that.

Comment: Sadly, I must agree; I think that `mingw-make` cannot run vbs, but I cannot test this hypothesis.

Comment: Okay, but thanks on your reading anyway! For users who are searching for a solution in future: I will write dynamically a batch file using 'echo helloworld.vbs > test.bat' and execute this file. This is not my favourite solution, but that works. Thanks Beta! (Is it possible to give a 'like'?)

Comment: You can praise a comment (although it is not necessary in this case). If you hover to the left of a comment, you will see two icons, an up-arrow to mark the comment as valuable, and a flag to mark it as bad. Marking it will not have the same effect as voting on an answer (it will not change anyone's reputation, nor promote the comment in a significant way), but that is appropriate since a comment is not as important as an answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks! There are no icons when I hover on comment. Maybe caused by my low ranking.